# A "Library"-folder appeared in my Documents folder on Mac, Is that normal?

Tags: macos, folders

After starting my computer I have seen a new folder called "Libary" that appeared in my documents folder on macOS. I can't access it, because, according to the prompt, I don't have permission, even though I have access as admin.

```
The folder “Library” can’t be opened because you don’t have permission to see its contents.
```

According to the information, it has a size of 0 bytes and was created today after starting up.
Is that normal, malware, or something else?

Comment: What *exact* version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @benwiggy macOS 10.14.16

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was reported by several of our users as well so I did some digging.

The Library folder itself is owned by root and only root has rwx access. The only folder inside on three different machines I tested was a Logs folder. This Logs folder was empty. All three machines had the same behavior and a similar setup. Deleting the folder was only temporary as it would return after a restart.

After some more digging and some input from Reddit users with the same issue, I believe it has to do with Adobe CC. I removed CC completely, deleted the folder, restarted and it hasn't come back. Before then it was coming back after every restart.

Adobe has published a patch to fix this folder (i.e. to not have it reappear again after you deleted it): https://helpx.adobe.com/download-install/kb/library-folder-created-on-macos.html

Comment: The same occurs to me and my colleagues and we are also using Adobe CC - so I think thepeel might be right about that one. On my private laptop, that does not have Adobe CC this library folder does not exist.

Comment: Found exactly the same thing, same circumstances. Also have Adobe CC. Started for me morning of March 4th.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, running 10.14.6. I also have Adobe CC installed.

Comment: Exactly the same for me as well. I also have Adobe CC, and a Library folder appeared inside my Documents folder dated March 4.

Comment: Adobe has published a patch to fix this folder (i.e. to not have it reappear again after you deleted it): https://helpx.adobe.com/download-install/kb/library-folder-created-on-macos.html

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing the same issue as you and other commenters, the Library folder is likely result of a bug following the 03/04/2021 Creative Cloud update. I had a message on the 4th stating I was signed out of CC app, and I quit the app instead, and at next launch was still logged in.

There are odd behaviors with this release. I am going to stop it from launching at startup until next release.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'normal', certainly. *(But every computer is different!)*
My first suspicion is that some software has got the path wrong, so instead of saving files to /Library, it's saving them to /Documents/Library.

I would open up the Terminal and see if there are any subfolders or zero-size files inside, which might give a clue to what's causing it. At the very least, you can delete it and see if, and when it grows back.

To see who owns the folder and what its permissions are:

```
cd ~/Documents
ls -l Library
```

To change the permissions so you can read the contents, something like:

```
sudo chmod -R a+r ~/Documents/Library
```

Alternatively, opening a root shell will allow you to inspect the contents in the Terminal.