# Cannot open folders in ~/Documents via alias or recent items

Tags: macos, folders, alias

I am having a similar issue as outlined in [A "Library"-folder appeared in my Documents folder on Mac, Is that normal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414851/a-library-folder-appeared-in-my-documents-folder-on-mac-is-that-normal?newreg=f165b71c5fbd45529d744d1c34014aa1) but with the added problem of I cannot open any folder located in `~/Documents` via an alias or recent items. All that opens when I try is just the root of the Mac HD. All of the folders and data are still present and the OS knows they are there because I am never asked to fix any of the aliases.

Have not had any luck finding a solution to getting these working again and welcome any input.

Comment: What  exact OS version? What program opens them - In Finder what does get Info show as the Original?

Comment: Big Sur 11.0.1. If I go through my alias of ~/Documents I can get to the files but any alias like ~/Documents/AnyFolder will not open. Get Info shows the correct path to the original (and even tried to reset to original and still no luck).

Comment: SO you have an alias to ~/Documents and using that alias makes other aliases unreadable? Note that is not what you describe in your question when you use ~/Documents directly

Comment: 11.0.1 was a bug-fest. i'd get up to date before even trying to fix this.

Comment: Using ~/Documents isn't making the others unreadable but it is my only path to get to those subfolders. So if I open the alias for ~/Documents and then browse to ~/Documents/Learning works as expected. If I use the alias for ~/Documents/Learning, it just opens the root for Mac HD.

I will try OS update and see what happens.

Comment: Just an update: completed the OS update to 11.2.3 and the issue is still occuring as follows: alias for ~/Documents works and I can access all files and folders. Any current or new alias for anything located inside ~/Documents opens to root of Mac HD (for example, ~/Documents/Learning I can navigate to but I cannot use an alias or Recent Items to go directly there).